# AWS dedicated tomcat server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm wondering if aws offers a simple solution like beanstalk which consist of tomcat but does not scale. I need to deploy a war that runs scheduled task and beanstalk kills my instances and scales thus messing up my scheduled jobs.

edit
I'm aware of creating a custom ec2 instance, I'm looking for something a little bit simpler like beanstalk, I'm not highly skilled in linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk supports [Single Instance Environments](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html). These environments won't scale.

Answer (score 2):

You can create Docker image using one of base images (For example: https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/), push it to ECR then deploy to ECS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_GetStarted.html

Answer (score 1):

create worker environment create yaml file with schedule information. for more information please read [aws guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html). this might solve your problem.